# Axiom Schema of Replacement

Tags: set-theory

Now the statement of it intuitively is rather simple, if i have a formula that is somewhat like a function, then i have, for any set, the "image" under that formula. Of course this is fairly simple with the the Pair Set Axiom and Induction, but i tried proving the existence of the set $\{a_1, a_2,\dots,a_k\}$ using Replacement with the set $\{1,2,\dots,k\}$ as domain however i did not come up with any formula, that would do that job (especially none that would be function-like.

Edit: I have an intuitive grasp of the axiomatic development of set theory up to cardinal arithmetic and further, so here i just tried to have an easy problem, which i would formally solve in an axiomatic way.

For a fixed natural number $k$: $1,2,\dots k$ should be the von-Neumann ordinals, and $a_1,\dots a_k$ arbitrary sets of which I want to show, that the set consisting of exactly those n elements exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply Replacement to the formula $\phi(x,y)$ which is $$(x=1\wedge y=a_1)\vee(x=2\wedge y=a_2)\vee\dots\vee(x=k\wedge y=a_k)$$ (note that in addition to the free variables $x$ and $y$, this formula also uses the sets $1,\dots,k,a_1,\dots,a_k$ as parameters).  Then if you know $X=\{1,\dots,k\}$ is a set, Replacement tells you that $$\{y:\exists x\in X (\phi(x,y))\}$$ is a set, and the elements of that set are exactly $a_1,\dots,a_k$.

As you mention, you can also prove this using Pairing and Induction, without needing Replacement.  The real power of Replacement is when you apply it to an *infinite* set.  In that case, you wouldn't be able to define your function by just listing out the elements as above.

Answer (score 0):

Replacement says if $\phi(x,\,y)$ holds for at most one $y$ per $x$, $\{y|\exists x\in S(\phi(x,\,y))\}$ is a set for any set $S$. Since $k$ is finite, you can take $\phi$ to be a disjunction of $k$ conjuncts,$$(x=1\land y=a_1)\lor\dots(x=k\land y=a_k).$$(This cannot be simplified to the more concise $y=a_x$ in the first-order theory.)